# Clustering in node.js fails in azure emulator or azure vm with EBADF

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-worker-roles

This classic cluster example:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case its a HTTP server

  // Worker code omitted
}
```

Runs smoothly on my windows machine using the windows azure PowerShell and a simple node process, however when I deploy it to the azure emulator or a to a real worker role machine I get the following error:

```
spawn EBADF
    at errnoException (child_process.js:837:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:789:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:614:9)
    at exports.fork (child_process.js:443:10)
    at new Worker (cluster.js:288:20)
    at Cluster.cluster.fork (cluster.js:474:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (X:\workspaces\tp\deploy\local_package.csx\roles\zealot\approot\server.js:8:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Anyone knows why this happens or how I can debug this problem ?

Thanks....

**UPDATE:** this problem seems to only occur in node engine >= 0.8.0

**UPDATE2:** opened an issue https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe this was fixed in node 0.8.7